# Hedging Options assuming a non-constant Yield Curve

Tags: options, option-pricing, interest-rates, yield-curve, resource

I have read most of Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II*. In it, the author prices various option types assuming an interest rate that is constant with respect to time.

We can expand this model using Hull-White to deal with stochastic interest rates. In this case, the interest rate is a stochastic process with respect to time.

In both of these scenarios, it appears to me that the "interest rate" is the short rate. Suppose you are hedging a short position in the call option. Suppose that the current value of the stock $S(t)$ at the current time $t$ requires a positive investment in the money market. A sudden change in $S$ from time $t$ to time $t+\epsilon$ could force the hedger to hold a negative investment in the money market. In this example, the hedger can flip from a positive investment to a negative investment in the money market in an arbitrarily small amount of time. That is why we are considering the short rate.

**The Question**

This all makes sense if the goal is a perfect hedge. However, yield curves are often not flat, and a hedger may decide that they will hold a positive position in they market account for a long period of time with *high probability*. This probability may be increased if the hedger is hedging options on multiple assets. In this case, the hedger may speculate by making a long term investment in the money market for the higher interest rate. Are there any good resources like books or research articles that talk about dealing with this situation?